# convert path to string bash

Tags: string, bash, path

I want to put multiple filepaths as a string in bash script, so I can pass this string to another program.
When I concatenate these filepaths I get the error: No such file or directory. Bash has to tread this filepath as a string instead of a file...

Im concatenating this way:

```
all=""
for path in $dir/*; do
    filePath="$path/file.txt"
    $all="$all I=$filePath"
done

echo $all
```

How can I get this output?

```
I=first/file.txt I=second/file.txt etc.
```

Comment: all="$all I=$filePath" have you try without initial $?

Comment: Something is wrong in your code: you don't use the loop variable `path` at all...

Comment: Made a little mistake in making this script simple ;) Problem was what Velthune mentioned...

Comment: You'd better use arrays!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is just your syntax wrong:

```
all=""
for path in $dir/*; do
    filePath="$dir/file.txt"
    all="$all I=$filePath"    #without $
done
echo $all
```

Comment: That was the problem... Why bash doesn't give the shell a syntax error instead of saying it is no file or dir -_-

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant to use `path`? And don't use $ as a prefix in assignments.

```
all=""
for path in $dir/*; do
    filePath="$path/file.txt"
    all="$all I=$filePath"
done
echo $all
```